# What's an efficient way to flatten/un-nest a nested object with an unknown level of nesting?

Tags: javascript

I have a nested object that has an unknown depth of nesting to it. Here is an example.

```
var a = 
[{
title: "parent1",
id: "1",
children: [{
    title: "child 1",
    id: 2,
    parentid: 1
}, {
    title: "child 2",
    id: 3,
    parentid: 1
}]
}, {
title: "parent 2",
id: 4,
children: [{
    title: "child 1",
    id: 5,
    parentid: 4,
    children: [{
        title: "GRAND CHILD",
        id: 6,
        parentid: 5
    }]
}]
}];`
```

Here is my code that i've tried... it works but only if i know how far down to unnest... it's also probably not the most efficient

```
function removeNesting(t){
      let flatTree = [];
          for(var i=0;i<t.length;i++){
          let parent = t[i];
          if(parent.children.length>0){
              for(var ii = 0;ii<parent.children.length;ii++){
                flatTree.push(parent.children[ii]);
              }
              //now that all the children are added to the flatTree remove 
        them from the parent and add the parent
              delete parent.children;
              flatTree.push(parent);
       }
      }
      return(flatTree);
    }
```

Any help would be great! Thanks!

I would love to have these all un-nested at any given level.

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use (upcoming) [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and get objects without children.

```js
const untree = ({ children = [], ...data }) => [data, ...children.flatMap(untree)];

var tree = [{ title: "parent1", id: "1", children: [{ title: "child 1", id: 2, parentid: 1 }, { title: "child 2", id: 3, parentid: 1 }] }, { title: "parent 2", id: 4, children: [{ title: "child 1", id: 5, parentid: 4, children: [{ title: "GRAND CHILD", id: 6, parentid: 5 }] }] }],
    result = tree.flatMap(untree);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: That's awesome and perfect! Thanks Nina!